# python - memory error

Tags: python, memory

When trying to load a large text file into memory I get this:

```
Python(24297,0xa0d291a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=717418496) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug 
MemoryError
```

The code that's causing it is:

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
        total = sum(1 for _ in f)
```

Is there a native python way to take care of this?

Comment: How much memory do you have on your system?

Comment: @sapi: Shouldn't that code use a generator and then not need to store the whole file in memory?

Comment: `wc -l list.txt` will solve it

Comment: What about on a windows system?

Comment: How long is the file?

Comment: `print len(f.readlines())` might work.

Comment: We're gonna need more information about your file. I created a test file with 316321918 lines of "Hello world " and 17127 lines of 10000 times "Hello world" and python never took more than 5MB memory for either of them. The only thing I noticed is that python was really bad at reading and writing (writing was as low as 40MBytes/s instead of ~450!).

Comment: Btw: what python version are you using?

Comment: 2.7.3, that's literally all thats in my file. I'm printing the total.

Comment: Well, there seems to be an issue with your hardware. Have you tried restarting your PC? If that doesn't help, try a memory checker. There might be a problem with your Memory. I'm not a memory export but it seems like your memory won't allow to create a certain region. That **might** be a memory issue, but I'm not too sure. If you could give me at least a little bit information about the file, light the actually file size and the approximately lines, I might be able to create another testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Wild guess:

You are running the above code on a binary file that contains no (or very few) newlines. Thus, the attempt to read one line reads one **very** long line.

Try this instead:

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    total = sum(block.count('\n')
                for block in iter(lambda: f.read(64*1024), ''))
```

Comment: @Matt3o12 - In your comment to the original post, you say that you created lines 110,000 bytes long. That's relatively short. Trying creating a 1GB file with no newlines in it. For example: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/list.txt bs=1M count=1K`.

Comment: `dd: count: illegal numeric value`. Anyway, I now have a third testcase that is almost 1GB and python still doesn't need more than 20MB.

Comment: Ok, I now have a 2GB file with only zeros, but python only took 2GB of my memory but crashed eventually: `SystemError: Negative size passed to PyString_FromStringAndSize`. 2,489,971,200 is too big for an integer. Anyway, with 16GB Ram, there should be a memory issue. Reading in chunks works fine, though (and it is quicker than I thought).

Comment: This worked, but it printed the count of 51 million lines (not just one)